# Let two functions run periodically with different 'sampling' times

Tags: python, scheduler

I already managed executing one function periodically with a specific sampling time `T` with the python scheduler from the `sched` package:

```
import sched
import time

def cycle(sche, T, fun, arg):
    sche.enter(T, 1, cycle, (sche, T, fun, arg))
    fun(arg)


def fun(arg):
    print(str(time.time()))
    print(arg)


def main():
    scheduler = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
    T = 1
    arg = "some argument"
    cycle(scheduler, T, fun, arg)
    scheduler.run()
```

What I would like to do is adding another function `fun2()`, that also will be executed periodically with another sample time `T2`.

What would be a proper way to do that?

Comment: What happens if you copy-paste what you have in your main, using `scheduler2`, `T2`, `fun2` etc.?

Comment: Maybe this [PyMOTW-3 article](https://pymotw.com/3/sched/index.html) will help.

Comment: @Guimoute That would not help cause as `scheduler1` is running 'forever' `scheduler2` would not even be started

Answer (score 1):

So for me the following solution worked: 
as I will have two CPU bound tasks I set up a multiprocessing environment with two processes. Each process starts an own scheduler that runs 'forever' with its own 'sampling' time.

What does anybody with more experience in python than me (I've just started :-D) think about this approach? Will it cause any problems in your opinion?

```
import time
import multiprocessing
import sched

global schedule1
global schedule2


def fun1(arg):
    print("Im the function that is executed every T1")
    time.sleep(0.05)  # do something for t < T1


def fun2(arg):
    print("Im the function that is executed every T2")
    time.sleep(0.8)  # do something for t < T2


def cycle1(scheduler1, T1, fun, arg):
    global schedule1
    try:
        schedule1.append(scheduler1.enter(T1, 1, cycle1, (scheduler1, T1, fun, arg)))
        fun1(arg)
        scheduler1.run()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        for event in schedule1:
            try:
                scheduler1.cancel(event)
            except ValueError:
                continue
        return


def cycle2(scheduler2, T2, fun, arg):
    global schedule2
    try:
        schedule2.append(scheduler2.enter(T2, 1, cycle2, (scheduler2, T2, fun, arg)))
        fun2(arg)
        scheduler2.run()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        for event in schedule2:
            try:
                scheduler2.cancel(event)
            except ValueError:
                continue
        return


def main():
    global schedule2
    global schedule1

    schedule2 = []
    schedule1 = []

    scheduler1 = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
    scheduler2 = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
    T1 = 0.1
    T2 = 1
    list_of_arguments_for_fun1 = []
    list_of_arguments_for_fun2 = []

    processes = []

    # set up first process
    process1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=cycle1, args=(scheduler1, T1, fun1, list_of_arguments_for_fun1))
    processes.append(process1)

    # set up second process
    process2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=cycle2, args=(scheduler2, T2, list_of_arguments_for_fun2, list_of_arguments_for_fun2))
    processes.append(process2)

    process1.start()
    process2.start()

    for process in processes:
        process.join()

    # anything below here in the main() won't be executed


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        start = time.perf_counter()
        main()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('\nCancelled by User. Bye!')
        finish = time.perf_counter()
        print(f'Finished in {round(finish - start, 2)} second(s)')
```

Comment: the problem with this solution is that both processes will sooner or later run into an recursion limit... does anybody have a solution for that?